# Amazon SP-API shipping V1 get rates endpoint

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am sending a post request to
https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/shipping/v1/rates with all the required data and perameters according to v1 swagger model given by sp-api documentation. Firstly i got some errors related to invalid values of in body but i set them all up. Now i am getting an error which is

`{ "errors": [ { "code": "InvalidInput", "message": "Invalid input.", "details": "AddressId cannot be blank while calling AAS:getDestinationInfo" } ] }`

the real problem is the whole body ( given by swagger model) doesn't have any key named "AddressId" and when i searched this error on google it doesn't show even one result... The documentation also couldn't help me.